# How to extract data from MULTIPLE XML files and put it in ONE XML file in spring batch?

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch

I already generated the java classes corresponding to my xml files (through jaxb tool).

Then I wrote my **configuration file** as following:

```
<batch:job id="bghJob" parent="simpleJob">

    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="xmlItemWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

</batch:job>


<!-- MULTI Reader -->
<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:xmls/*.xml" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="xmlItemReader" />
</bean>

<!-- Reader -->
<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="T_Document" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="invoiceUnMarshaller" />
</bean>

<!-- Unmarshaller -->
<bean id="invoiceUnMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.xxx.model.inputJaxB" />
</bean>

<!-- Writer -->
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/Facture.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="invoiceMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="Facture" />
</bean>

<!-- Marshaller -->
<bean id="invoiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx.model.output.Facture</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**and here is my App.java:**

```
public class App {

public static long customerID = 201832;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] springConfig = { "spring/batch/config/context.xml", "spring/batch/jobs/job-bgh.xml" };

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("bghJob");

    try {

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

}

**My problem is that the xml output file created is almost empty**. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Facture></Facture>
```

**What am I missing please ??? Why is my output xml empty?**

---

**EDIT:**

My Facture.java class for the output xml:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "T_Document")
```

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Facture {

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "Sender", required = true)
private String sender;

@XmlAttribute(name = "Id", required = true)
private String id;

@XmlAttribute(name = "BAId", required = true)
private String baId;

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String value) {
    this.sender = value;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String value) {
    this.id = value;
}

public String getBAId() {
    return baId;
}

public void setBAId(String value) {
    this.baId = value;
}
```

}

Comment: are you sure classpath:xmls/*.xml return a not-empty file list?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. There is 7 xml files there

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci any other idea please ?

Comment: nope, sorry. At this point try setting SB' log level to DEBUG and watch

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I though it was maybe the java class of for output.. maybe something is wrong there...

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci How can I set spring batch log level to debug please?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/log4j.properties

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I executed my app with the log level set to DEBUG. I don't really know how to identify a problem there. However, I noticed this : "PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:93 - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]". Can it be the problem origin? Would you like to see all the debug log?